# How can I create a multipoint geometry in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geometry, spatialite

I've got a Spatialite layer in QGIS with geometry type MULTIPOINT. Now I'd like to add some data in this table in the 'usual' way, so by doing multiple clicks in the map (e.g. left-click, left-click, right-click -> enter attribute values in the popup dialog for creating a record with a 3-points geometry. However, QGIS only allows me to add a single point by popping up the attribute dialog right after the first left-click.

How to do this in the GUI? (I don't want to enter coordinates by hand in a query :-) )

Answer (score 10):

You should proceed as if you are working with a polygon with multiple parts.

- Start editing your layer;
- Add a point;
- Enter the attributes in the form and press ok;
- Select that point with any selection tool;
- Click on "Add part", in the Advanced Digitalizing toolbar;

After that you can add as many point as you want to your multipoint feature, without the need to fill the attributes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ahh didn't know that worked like that :)

Comment: Hi Alexandre, Thanks, that works for me and is less cumbersome than merging selected features as proposed by Nathan. However, in my opinion, for a 3-point feature the most intuitive way would be: Select the multipoint layer, toggle editing on, go in add feature mode, lay down the points in the map by left-click, left-click, right-click -> enter attribute values in the attribute entry form.

Comment: Yes I agree that for multipoint features that would be preferable. In the other hand, if you wanted to digitalize single point features that would require two clicks (left-click, right click) for each point, where it only need one now. It shouldn't be difficult to make a plugin for the functionality you want.

Answer (score 2):

What you will need to do is merge all the geometries together after you have created the points.

1. Create each point
2. Select which points should go together
3. Merge them

   [image]

This will create a single "feature" with multi geometries

[image]

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks, that works for me. However, it would be nice to have the option to add multipoint features in a less cumbersome way, as described in my question. Do you agree?

Comment: How would you want that to work?

Comment: E.g. for a 3-point feature the most intuitive way for me would be: Select the multipoint layer, toggle editing on, go in add feature mode, lay down the points in the map by left-click, left-click, right-click -> enter attribute values in the attribute entry form.